# $S$-matrix in tree approximation in QED vs scattering theory with Coulomb potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering

Let one has two different particles with charges $e_1,e_2$. One can compute the $S$-matrix for their scattering with momenta $p_1,p_2$ and spins $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ to momenta $p_{1'},p_{2'}$ and spins $\sigma_1',\sigma_2'$ using perturbative methods of QED. Thus in tree approximation in non-relativistic limit one recovers the Coulomb law:
$$S(1,2\to 1'2')= \frac{-i}{4\pi^2} \delta^4(p_{1'}+p_{2'}-p_1-p_2)\delta_{\sigma_1'\sigma_1}\delta_{\sigma_2\sigma_2}\int d^3r V(r)e^{-i\vec q\vec r}$$
where $\vec q=p_{1'}-p_1=p_2-p_{2'}$ and $V$ is the Coulomb potential (thus 
$\int d^3r V(r)e^{-i\vec q\vec r}=e_1e_2 \frac{1}{\vec q^2}$).
(This can be found e.g. in Section 11.2 of Weinberg's "The quantum theory of fields" where additionally one computes some of the one-loops corrections.))

> My question is how this result is compatible with the results obtained by the methods of non-relativistic scattering theory? As far as I understand the whole machinery of the scattering theory is not applicable since the Coulomb potential does not decay fast enough, in particular there is no such a thing as Born approximation  of $S$-matrix (correct me if I am wrong). Nevertheless there is another, stationary, approach which works for the Coulomb potential (see e.g. Section 135 of Landau-Lifshitz, vol. III). **I would like to see how the above expression for the $S$-matrix is compatible with Section 135 in Landau-Lifshitz.**

Comment: section 135 of L&L addresses the exchange effects of scattering of two _identical_ particles, so that is not relevant for the QED calculation; an earlier section 133 considers the case of distinct particles, with an expression in equation 133.9 that is much more complicated than the one you write down here, simply because 133.9 goes beyond the Born approximation. The simple integral over $V(r)$ appears at tree-level in the QED calculation, which corresponds to the Born approximation in the nonrelativistic calculation.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Probably we are talking about different editions of L&L with different numeration. Anyway, my actual question is what is the non-relativistic calculation whose Born approximation you referred to? I thought that for Coulomb potential it should be very different than for rapidly decaying potentials. I think the Born approximation you mentioned has been obtained if one substitutes into the general formula for Born approximation the Coulomb potential, but this is not legal probably.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker At the moment it is fine with me not to go beyond Born approximation unless it is avoidable for any reason.